# For $3x^2 + 2kx +k-1 =0$; find the value of $k$ for which the roots of the equation are closest together

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, quadratics

For $3x^2 + 2kx +k-1 =0$; find the value of $k$ for which the roots of the equation are closest together

So my first approach to the problem was to find when the discriminant = 0 and then round off or something, however this problem was in the non-calculator section of a worksheet... anyone have any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Is $k$ meant to be an integer?  Seems like you're just meant to minimize $k^2-3k+3$, no?

Comment: The distance between the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ is $\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{a}$, which you can minimize (as long as it's positive) by minimizing its square $\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}$. In this case this amounts to minimizing a certain quadratic polynomial in $k$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: As far as I can see the OP has not said _anything_ that can conceivably be understood as a requirement that $k$ must be an integer. Such a requirement seems to be entirely the product of Lulu's imagination.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you are right, it is not written that $k$ should be an integer. In number theory it is, sometimes. So it does not seem far-fetched. But why do you want to assume something else? That is also not written. Should not the OP start to say something?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  There's also no statement that $k\in \mathbb R$, yet I assume that this was intended.  But, really, I was just asking for clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In $x^2-px+q$, $p$ is the sum and $q$ the product of the roots, and the discriminant $D=p^2-4q$ is the square of the difference of the roots. It seems you want to minimize $|D|$.

Answer (score 2):

I will interpret your question as for an equation $3x^2+2kx+k-1=0$ with two real roots, find $k$ corresponding to the least $|x_1-x_2|$.

Thus, we first calculate the discriminant; this gives that $4k^2-4\times3\times(k-1)\geq0$, but this holds for all $k$.

Thus, we can use the Vieta's theorems.

We observe that $|x_1-x_2|_{min}$ corresponds to $(x_1-x_2)^2_{min}$; but $(x_1-x_2)^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-4x_1x_2=(\frac{2k}{3})^2-4\frac{k-1}{3}$, and the minimum is reached when $k=\frac{3}{2}$.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

the reduced discriminant of your equation is

$\delta=k^2-3(k-1)$

$=(k-\frac{3}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}>0$.

the roots $a$ and $b$ are such
$|a-b|=\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\delta}$.

they are closest together if

$\delta$   is  minimal, which gives

$k=\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute difference between the roots of a quadratic equation is $$\frac{\sqrt\Delta}{2|a|}$$

and in your case it suffices to minimize the discriminant,

$$k^2-3k+3.$$ This occurs when $2k-3=0$.